# Named or Standard Circuits

Tags: analog, circuit-design

BJT amplifiers have a few standard configurations, i.e. Class A, B, A/B. Likewise there are a variety of standard OP-Amp circuits such as summing circuits and filters.

Is there a publicly available catalog of these standard circuits? I know companies have their own private libraries of circuits, but I have never seen anything similar in the public domain.

Comment: There are different books on amplifier design. I guess one can consider them publicity available.

Comment: I'd recommend these books: "Analog Circuit Design: Art, Science, and Personalities" by Jim Williams; "The Art and Science of Analog Circuit Design" by Jim Williams; and "The Art of Electronics", 2nd or 3rd edition, by Paul Horowitz and Winfield Hill.

Comment: And how about the internet itself? Enter "opamp circuit" in Google search and press the **images** tab: hundreds of circuits.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie true, but I would prefer peer reviewed sources

Comment: *I would prefer peer reviewed sources* Oh, you want guarantees? Experts that can do "peer reviews" are expensive, now you know why such IP libraries are company secret or cost serious money. Anyway, in the end you will still need a **circuit designer** to design the circuit that you need (assuming the application diagram of some IC doesn't do what you need). So even having a "peer reviewed library with circuits" is often not as useful as it sounds.

Comment: @Craeft In the case of novel and innovative (read: bleeding edge) electronics, I think you'll find peer review more part of the process. NASA almost certainly runs various instrument designs through peer-review before packaging and launching them into space. But you are talking about relatively routine topics where the engineering is far more about balancing tradeoffs between constraints: low energy, small size, low mass, mutli-source parts, vibration tolerance, ambient interference tolerance, conveniences, cost, price to consumer, after sale support, etc. Not sure how that's peer reviewed.

Comment: I think -- particularly given the "peer reviewed" comment, that you're thinking that circuit design is a science, done by scientists.  Actually, scientists are generally fairly poor at circuit design -- they make something good enough to get their data, write their article (which is peer reviewed), then put the circuit in the junk heap.  Engineering is a **craft**.  The real "peer review" happens when you make a product that works, and continues to work for a good long time.  That doesn't happen because a bunch of PhD's with no practical experience liked your work.

Answer (score 1):

How about these free resources:

"Op Amps for Everyone", Ron Mancini (Texas Instruments)

"Linear Circuit Design Handbook", Hank Zumbahlen (Analog Devices)

Comment: These are certainly in the right direction, but I was hoping for a more universal collection. Possibly something online, even. I would also be in favor of the answers to this question being a large list of appropriate books.

Comment: What do you mean by online? They are both online? If you want a list of books, have you read the Wikipedia pages for op-amps and transistos? Although, any university class book on electronic basics should teach these.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a basic misconception of standard circuits. Class A, B, and A/B are designations of classes of amplifiers usually those supplying significant amounts of power. They can be constructed from BJT's, FETs. vacuum tubes, etc. Similarly summing circuits and filters are also basic configurations and are not restricted to just op amps. There have been many books published which have collections of typical circuits of these types as well as many others such as multivibrators, oscillators, radios, etc. Any of the standard textbooks on introductory electrical engineering will have discussions on these types of circuits. For more detail, you should look at books on specific topics such as power amplifiers, filters, radios, etc. Various manufacturers published handbooks for their products which had many typical circuits. These date back to vacuum tubes with RCA a prime source.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this knowledge has never been standardized in a formal way.

This knowledge is available on many books.

Comment: I suspect you right, but I hope you are wrong ;)